# Find a linear function whose graph is the plane that intersects the xy plane along the line.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have an exam in an hour and this one question is killing me! We enter our answers online so maybe I am just entering it wrong, but I can't for the life of me seem to get it right.. any help?

Find a linear function whose graph is the plane that intersects the xy plane along the line y=x+8 and contains the point (2,2,16)

Somehow, the solution shows

y= x + 8, we have b /= 0

-a/b = 1, -c/b=8

Since (2,2,16) lies on the place we can use the equation z=ax+by+c to get

16 = 2a + 2b + 16c

Solving the solution gives

a=2
b=-2
c=16

giving 2x - 2y + 16

I just don't get it!

Comment: I can't follow your solution.  You should start by defining that the equation we are looking for is $ax+by+c=z$-at the first appearance of $a,b,c$ we have no idea what they are.  Even so, I don't see how you get to $-a/b=1,-c/b=8$  From there you have three equations in three unknowns and your solution is not correct.  $2a+2b+16c=256$  It should be $c=1$

Comment: These solutions are from "WileyPlus." I literally spent hours last night trying to get the right answer, but never could, always coming up different from the Wiley answers. One of the laziest prof's I have ever had to assign online math homework. Thanks for clarification on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  pick any two points on the line.  The cross product of the vectors from $(2,2,16)$ to the two points is a normal to the plane.

Comment: I should have stated that we aren't using the cross product yet.. he uses a weird method I will update my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the equation of the line of intersection in the $ \ xy-$ plane ( $  z = 0  $ ) written in "general form" as  $ \ -x + y = 8 \ , $ we can construct an equation for the tilted plane, also in "general form", as

$$ -Kx \ + \ Ky \ + \ cz \ = \ 8K \ , $$

the constant $ \ K \ $ being introduced to allow us a little "freedom" in the construction for the moment.  This plane must contain the point $ \ (2, 2, 16) \ , $ so we have

$$ -2K \ + \ 2K \ + \ 16c \ = \ 8K \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2c \ = \ K \ . $$

Since any non-zero value for $ \ K \ $ will do, we may simply choose $ \ c = 1 \ $ to write an equation for the plane as

$$ -2x \ + \ 2y \ + \ z \ = \ 16 \ \ . $$

(The problem statement appears to be asking for the form $ \ z = 16 + 2x - 2y \ . $ )

This approach is analogous to finding, for example, the constant term $ \ C \ $ in the general equation for a line in the plane $ \ Ax \ + \ By \ = \ C \ $ , for specified coefficients $ \ A \ \text{and} \ B \ , $ passing through a specified point $ \ ( x_0 , y_0 ) \ . $